# Switch between same child and parent in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can we callback to same child from parent ? I have scenario as given below:
**HTML**

```
<div id="abc123">
<ul id="pqr">
    <span class="abc">ChildA</span>
    <span class="xyz">ChildB</span>
</ul>
```

**javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('.abc, .xyz').parent().click(function()
   {
      alert($(this).children().attr("class"));
   });
});
```

**HTML output:**

```
ChildA ChildB
```

Whenever I am clicking on **childA** it gives me correct output as **abc** but when I am clicking on **childB** it again targeting to 1st child and giving its attribute as **abc**
Is there any way to to target to same children to whom I clicked on ?

Comment: remove the `parent()`

Comment: is there any way, without removing parent() ?

Comment: what are you expecting when you click on `childB`

Comment: @PhilippSander I am expecting to get alert with class name xyz

Comment: @Aman so, you want the class of the child you clicked returned? then take a look at my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by referring to the DOM element that initiated the event.:

```
$('.abc, .xyz').parent().click(function (e) {
    alert($(e.target).attr("class"));
});
```

Demo: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QmSsv/)

---

`event or e` is actually the [`event object`](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) and is guaranteed to be passed to the event handler. Most properties from the original event are copied over and normalized to the new event object.

[`e.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) is one of the main event property and it is the element that registered for the event or a descendant of it.

Comment: @palash will you please try to explain a bit about this **e** argument and what does this `e.target` do ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('.abc, .xyz').click(function()
   {
      alert($(this).attr("class"));
   });
});
```

Comment: no way... since I need to click on parent rather than children

Comment: If you want a listener on the parent what criteria you want to apply to alert child 1 or 2?

Comment: @GirishSakhare have a look on palash answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('.abc, .xyz').parent().click(function(event)
   {
      alert(event.target.attr('class'));
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
$("#pqr span").click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr("class");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`parent().children()` returns an array with both elements in it (ChildA and ChildB)

when you call a method on that array, it always uses the first element (ChildA)

apply the click listener to both elements and get the class from the object you clicked (`this`) and don't try to get it via parent and children.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('.abc, .xyz').click(function()
   {
      alert($(this).attr("class"));
   });
});
```

Comment: have a look on @palash answer

Answer (score 0):

Binding a click event on parent and then finding attributes of it's children will give you the same results as you are getting to get the exact output either you can compare the class name or compare them by id.

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
   $('#pqr').find('span').click(function()
   {
      alert($(this).attr("class"));
   });
});
```